# How to make bubble sort in Flat Assembler?

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort, fasm

I wrote some code for bubble sort in c++. Now I want to write it in flat assembler but it seems harder than I expected. Can someone help or provide relevant sources?
Here is my c++ code:

```
int[] arr= {5,8,7,4,1,9}
int n =6    //array size

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){   
// Last i elements are already in place
             for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
                            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                                             int x=arr[j];
                                            arr[j] = arra[j+1];
                                             arr[j+1] = x
                            }
}
}

For (int i=0; I < n ;i++){
            Cout << “  ”+arr[i]+ “  ” ;
}
```

Comment: There are several existing NASM BubbleSort implementations, and  FASM syntax is close enough to NASM.  (Unfortunately the first page of google results for `site:stackoverflow.com nasm bubble sort` is either unanswered, or only in comments.)  But anyway, we're not going to do your homework for you; you need to at least make an attempt *in asm*; you can start by translating each C statement one at a time, like a debug-mode compiler would.  Otherwise you might as well just use a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The (now classic) snippet for bubble sort is:

```
; by Andrew Howe

outerloop:  lea     ebx,[edi+ecx*4]
            mov     eax,[edi]
cmploop:    sub     ebx,4
            cmp     eax,[ebx]
            jle     notyet
            xchg    eax,[ebx]
notyet:     cmp     ebx,edi
            jnz     cmploop
            stosd
            loop    outerloop
```

You'd just define your array of data and pass the address in EDI, and the number of items in the array in ECX.

I first saw it at [AZillionMonkeys](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/asmexample.html).

Comment: `xchg` is good for code size, but very slow.  (Implicit `lock` prefix, so it's an atomic RMW with a full memory barrier.)  Also, it's weird to use EBX but not EDX; in most calling conventions, EBX is call-preserved but EDX can be clobbered.

Comment: This looks optimized for code-size over speed, mostly.  I think it's mostly the same algorithm as my codegolf.SE answer on [Sort an Integer List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038) (but that version is more heavily golfed for size at the expense of speed, e.g. uses `scasd` in the inner loop, and copies ECX to count-down instead of using an end-pointer).

Comment: Anyway, **this algorithm is JumpDown Sort, not Bubble Sort** - it swaps every time you find a new min, not necessarily adjacent elements.  See  [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/papers/bubble.pdf).  That's why one exchange between reg and memory in the inner loop can work, and why a store after the inner loop (`stosd`) is needed.  It's a hybrid of Selection Sort and Bubble Sort.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I've been thinking this was bubble sort for 20+ years.  I've never actually used it in software since quick sort is not that large code-wise, but have always enjoyed the code density of the creative mind.